# Can't dynamically load a script from node_modules

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

I use this standard method to load scripts dynamically.

```
import {Injectable} from "@angular/core";
import {ScriptStore} from "./script.store";

declare var document: any;

@Injectable()
export class ScriptService {

private scripts: any = {};

constructor() {
    ScriptStore.forEach((script: any) => {
        this.scripts[script.name] = {
            loaded: false,
            src: script.src
        };
    });
}

load(...scripts: string[]) {
    var promises: any[] = [];
    scripts.forEach((script) => promises.push(this.loadScript(script)));
    return Promise.all(promises);
}

loadScript(name: string) {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        //resolve if already loaded
        if (this.scripts[name].loaded) {
            resolve({script: name, loaded: true, status: 'Already Loaded'});
        }
        else {
            //load script
            let script = document.createElement('script');
            script.type = 'text/javascript';
            script.src = this.scripts[name].src;
            if (script.readyState) {  //IE
                script.onreadystatechange = () => {
                    if (script.readyState === "loaded" || script.readyState === "complete") {
                        script.onreadystatechange = null;
                        this.scripts[name].loaded = true;
                        resolve({script: name, loaded: true, status: 'Loaded'});
                    }
                };
            } else {  //Others
                script.onload = () => {
                    this.scripts[name].loaded = true;
                    resolve({script: name, loaded: true, status: 'Loaded'});
                };
            }
            script.onerror = (error: any) => resolve({script: name, loaded: false, status: 'Loaded'});
            document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0].appendChild(script);
        }
    });
}

}
```

The problem is that it works only for external paths. With this setup I can't get bootstrap-datepicker.js loaded but it is loaded when 'https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/...' is used. Can anyone help? Should I somehow make that script available using routes?

```
interface Scripts {
  name: string;
  src: string;
}
export const ScriptStore: Scripts[] = [
  { name: "paypal", src: "https://www.paypalobjects.com/api/checkout.min.js" },
  {
    name: "datepicker",
      src: "../../../../node_modules/bootstrap-datepicker/js/bootstrap-datepicker.js"
      //"https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-datepicker/1.9.0/js/bootstrap-datepicker.min.js"
  },
  {
    name: "datepickerEs",
    src:
      "https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-datepicker/1.9.0/locales/bootstrap-datepicker.es.min.js"
  }
];
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, you should make that script available through your assets.

Scripts in your node_modules get **compiled** and **bundled** to end up in a single script, usually `vendor.js`. If you have a single script file, then you can't use lazy loading on it.

To do that, extract the script from the node modules, put it in an assets folder, and use that script location to lazy load.